# Shortest Route in a Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, routes

I want to find the shortest path in this for an NXN MATRIX like the 3X3 matrix below. starting at any row of column 1 and ends at any row of column 3. The shortest path in the matrix A below is 1, 3, 2, 4.

```
A = [1 3 9; 
     4 2 4;
     5 4 9];
```

Comment: shortest path to where? if you just want to end at column 3, wouldn't 1-3-9 be shorter? or is the value of the matrix entry related to its cost?

Comment: If the latter is the case, you might want to look into pathfinding algorithms such as A* pathfinding. A good link to get you started is here: http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm . In the 'notes on implementation' at the bottom of the page they also explain how to add a cost to each tile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes the value of the matrix entry is related to cost

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to first represent your problem as a graph. In your case, if you treat each cell in your matrix as a vertex, there is an edge from that vertex to the cell on the right, the cell above, and the cell below (any one of which may not exist because they fall off the edge of the matrix). Backtracking to a previous column cannot contribute to a shortest path, so we don't include those edges. If you did include them, the answer would come out the same, it just might take a fraction longer.

Using index numbering, then, we have the following edges and weights:

```
 i j  s
[1,2]=4
[1,4]=3
[2,1]=1
[2,3]=5
[2,5]=2
[3,2]=4
[3,6]=4
[4,5]=2
[4,7]=9
[5,4]=3
[5,6]=4
[5,8]=4
[6,5]=2
[6,9]=9
[7,8]=4
[8,7]=9
[8,9]=9
[9,8]=4
```

(The labels i,j and s are used below.) But this doesn't account for the initial cost of moving to the first column, so we add a new node that has edges to each of those nodes:

```
  i j  s
[10,1]=1
[10,2]=4
[10,3]=3
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found a clever way of doing this, but it's fairly straightforward and once you're finished you have the 3 column vectors you need to create a sparse matrix using:

```
S = sparse(i,j,s,m,n,nzmax)
```

where

```
i,j,s are column vectors as labeled from the edge/weight list above
m = n = numel(A)+1
nzmax = numel(i) = numel(j) = numel(s)
```

From there you would use [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the single-source shortest path starting from the new node `10`. Your answer would be the node on the rightmost column (node 7, 8 or 9, in this case) with the smallest path distance.

If you have the bioinformatics toolbox, you can use [shortestpath](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/shortestpathbiograph.html). If you don't, there are several implementations of Dijkstra's on File Exchange.